# Можно ли использовать значение переменной в качестве метки для перехода goto?

Tags: c++, goto

Есть следующий код:

```
int main() {    
    goto s;
    return 1;
s:
    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли составить равносильный ему, но вместо фиксированного лейбла `s` использовать символ?

Псевдокод:

```
int main() {
    char str = 's';
    goto str;  
    return 1;
s:
    return 0;  
}
```

*Нельзя использовать никакие условные операторы.*

Comment: Конечно же нельзя. Зачем вам это? Почему бы не использовать обычный `if`?

Comment: Если *Нельзя использовать никакие условные операторы* , то goto тем более не следует.

Comment: [Is it possible to store the address of a label in a variable and use goto to jump to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777990/is-it-possible-to-store-the-address-of-a-label-in-a-variable-and-use-goto-to-jum)

Comment: Символ нельзя, но переменную для перехода по меткам можно в GNU-расширении

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В компиляторе от GNU можно.

Только не напрямую, а используя символ в качестве индекса в массиве меток.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  void *p[] = {&&L1, &&L2};
  unsigned char c;

  scanf("%c", &c);
  goto *p[c & 1];

 L1:
  printf("'%c' is even code %d\n", c, c);
  goto fin;
 L2:
  printf("'%c' is odd code %d\n", c, c);

 fin:
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ g++ tf.c
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
a       
'a' is odd code 97
End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
b
'b' is even code 98
End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

P.S.
извините, но для всех символов мне было лень набивать...

Comment: "О, мсье понимает толк в извращениях!" (с) Анекдот - это не о вас, понятно, а о GNUсных программистах :)

Answer (score 6):

Читаем стандарт:

> 8.7.5 The goto statement [stmt.goto]
>
> The goto statement unconditionally transfers control to the statement labeled by the identifier. The identifier shall be a label (8.2) located in the current function.

Оператор `goto` безусловно передаёт управление инструкции, обозначенной идентификатором. Этот идентификатор должен быть **меткой**, расположенной в текущей функции.

Соответственно ни о каких переменных в `goto` речи быть не может. Более того, возможно одновременное существование меток и переменных с одинаковым названием:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int p = 42;
    goto p;
    std::cout << "not printed\n";
    p: std::cout << p << "\n";
}
```

Однако, как подсказали в комментарии, существует [GNU расширение](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html), позволяющее использовать метки как значения.

Comment: [Вообще-то может](https://godbolt.org/z/jWs3Ej), однако это нестандартное расширение.

Comment: @user7860670 какому воспалённому мозгу такое могло понадобиться?

Comment: Надо же, в g++ тоже сделали (раньше только в gcc было). А использовать можно для эффективной  реализации [FSM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82)

Answer (score 4):

Раз уж зашла речь об извращениях, вот решение для Visual C++ (только x86):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<char, void*> labels;
#define GOTO(x) {void* tmp=labels[x];__asm {jmp tmp}}
#define SAVE_LABEL(x,name) {void* tmp;__asm {mov tmp, offset x};labels[name]=tmp;}

int main() {

    SAVE_LABEL(s, 's');
    SAVE_LABEL(p, 'p'); 
    GOTO('p')

    printf("Hello, world!\n");

s:  printf("Hello from s!\n");
    return 1;

p:  printf("Hello from p!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Суть способа в том, что хоть goto и не может переходить к переменным, но вот инструкции безусловного перехода, которую он использует, абсолютно наплевать, к чему переходить.

Это приводит нас к такому ассемблерному коду для перехода

```
__asm {jmp x}
```

где x - произвольный адрес.

И к такому для получения адреса метки:

```
__asm {mov x, offset y}
```

где x - переменная, y - имя метки.

Но тут следует понимать, что ассемблерные вставки непереносимы и мешают компилятору оптимизировать код функции, в которой они присутствуют. Поэтому если вы хотели таким образом состряпать какое-то высокоэффективное решение с таблицами переходов, скорее всего, ничего не выйдет.